# a additional BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I just got a little problem. I found this code:

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc]initWithMapView:self.mapView];
[self.mapToolbar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObject:trackingButton] animated:YES];
```

and I want to add an additional button on the right side (at left is the tracking button). 
**NOTE** 
its is a UIToolbar not a navigationbar

so i just tried this:

```
   MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc]initWithMapView:self.mapView];
    UIBarButtonItem* rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pins" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(rightButton:)];
    [self.mapToolbar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackingButton, rightButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

but it isn't working any ideas?

**EDIT** 
I updated the code: added button to NSArray

Comment: You are not adding rightButton to the toolBar.

Comment: my knowledge about buttons is very limited and they confusing me in some cases. How do I add it?

Comment: http://brianflove.com/2012/10/01/uitoolbar-for-simple-and-easy-toolbars-in-ios/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a tool bar button to be "right justified" on toolbar you need to add a flexible space item in the array in between the item on the left and the item on the right.

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc]initWithMapView:self.mapView];
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem* rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pins" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(rightButton:)];
[self.mapToolbar setItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:trackingButton, flexible, rightButton, nil] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" style:UIBarStyleDefault target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];
```

Comment: This isn't a `toolbarItem`. I have a `Toolbar` not a `navigationbar`